# Stop video when I change the state in angular

Tags: angularjs, html5-video

I am playing a video in a template in angular. But when I change the state the video remains playing.

The video playing is here:

http://localhost:8000/app/#/practice

But when I change to this:

http://localhost:8000/app/#/adjust

The video in the first state remains playing.

Can anyone help me please?

This is my configuration:

`.state('app.adjust',{
            url: 'adjust',
            views:{
                'content@':{
                    templateUrl : 'views/adjust_lesson.html',
                    controller  : 'AdjustLesson'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.practice',{
            url: 'practice',
            views:{
                'content@':{
                    templateUrl : 'views/practice_lesson.html',
                    controller: 'PracticeLesson'
                }
            }
        });`

And this is inside my index.html

`<div ui-view = 'header'></div>
<div ui-view = 'content'></div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop the video when 'PracticeLesson' controller is destroyed.

In 'PracticeLesson' put the following code, it will be called when the controller changes to 'AdjustLesson' when you change state.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    // anything here will be executed when this scope is destroyed.
});
```